# string capture between duplicates in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

```
string = 'xabcdexfghijk'
```

In the example above, 'x' appears twice. I want to capture everything between the first 'x' and the next 'x'. Thus, the desired result is a new string that equals 'xabcdex'. Any ideas?

Comment: When you ask a question like this, you're supposed to show us what you've tried, otherwise it looks like you're hoping someone will do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple regular expression: `/x.*?x/`. This basically means "match any characters in between two `x` characters, *as few times as possible* (non-greedy)".

The matched text can be extracted with [`String#[regexp]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)

```
string = 'xabcdexfghijk'
string[/x.*?x/] # => "xabcdex"
```

Comment: ahh perfect, thanks August! just what I was looking for. I still have a few minutes until I can accept. Thanks!